# calculating total revenues (price*quantity) in Rstudio

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIRvK.png)
Hello everyone,

I need to work with the data presented above. This question involves a little bit of knowledge of Rstudio. I would (1) like to obtain total revenue PER product (ucp), and brand, (2) sum all observations from product and brands, (3) and then pick up a product (ucp) and brand with largest total revenue in data. (4) Lastly, I would like to create a scatterplot (prices y axis; sales x axis), then fit a straight and quadratic line into the data of the graph.

For now I am stuck with (1), for which I have done the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bhrG.png)

I am not sure how to proceed further, I am not familiar with coding. Again, the name of my data set is "mydata", variables are (upc), and (brand). If anything is unclear, I am attentive and will edit.

I tried using the code

```
mydata %>% group_by(upc) %>% summarize(revenue = sum(Sales*Price))
```

but I am not sure if this allows me to complete the task

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at introductory R courses (Rstudio is not a programming language but merely an [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)). It is meaningless to just copy paste some code when you do not understand it. Knowing the basics of coding is an important skill to have. The language does not really matter because your boss will anyhow tell you what you need to use. Once you get a decent understanding of programming, switching to a different language is often fairly simple (at least for simple tasks like the one you describe).

In your example, assuming you have your dataframe, somewhat simplified, you could look at:

```
upc <- c(1, 1,3,1,2,3,4,5, 1)
sales <- c(17,9,5,7,4,6,8,2, 4)
price <- c(1.59, 1.79, 1.56, 1.83, 1.56, 1.54, 1.53, 1.8, 1.78)
brand <- c("Bud", "Bud", "Bud", "Cola", "Bud", "Cola", "Bud", "Bud", "Bud")
city <- c("Chicago", "Aurora", "Chicago", "Buffalo Grove", "Chicago", "Joliet", "R Land", "Arlington", "Chicago")

df <- data.frame(upc, sales, price, brand, city)
```

[image]

You can directly group by several criteria.

```
df_grouped <- df %>%
  group_by(brand, upc, city) %>%
  summarize(rev = sum(sales*price))
```

[image]

You can obtain the max revenue in numerous ways, one of which is

```
print(max(df_grouped$rev))
```

To plot, you can google something like [ggplot scatter](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=ggplot+scatter), where ggplot is a visualization package for R. Clicking on the first suggestion brings up a [solution](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) for your question in my case. Rewriting the syntax to the variables used in this example would look something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=price, y=sales)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) +  ggtitle("Title: Default is left-aligned")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for. Hands down!